# Not receiving characters from the keyboard

Tags: c#, keyboard

I used this code to change the keyboard language. But even after deleting those ,combo boxes and text boxes that have _KeyDown events written on them, they do not receive input characters from the keyboard.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool SystemParametersInfo(uint uiAction, uint uiParam, ref uint pvParam, uint fWinIni);
public void Foo()
{
    uint localeUS = 0x00000409;
    uint localeNL = 0x00000403;
    SetSystemDefaultInputLanguage(localeUS);
}

public bool SetSystemDefaultInputLanguage(uint locale)
{
    return SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETDEFAULTINPUTLANG, 0, ref locale, 0);
}

public uint GetSystemDefaultInputLanguage()
{
    uint result = uint.MinValue;
    bool retVal = SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETDEFAULTINPUTLANG, 0, ref result, 0);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Why do't you use the [InputLanguage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.inputlanguage) class for this?

Comment: I am currently using Input Language. But once I executed this code and deleted it, it is still effective